# Anime with monsters contained in cards

Tags: story-identification, anime

I was searching Google trying to find an anime I saw 6 to 8 years ago and found [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222502/a-card-monster-anime-that-is-not-yu-gi-oh) post from late 2019 and no one successfully answered the question so I'm reposting it, I'm pretty sure that the post is talking about the same anime (if not the plots are near identical).

Here is a copy of the original post:

> There is a group of friends that have those cards which can activate some monsters and they can battle other people like that. In that anime there are Death Eaters OGs that were a cult like group with tattoos. A brother of one character is in that cult and then when needed he confesses and tries to help them save the world from that cult organization. The head of the cult has this one monster that can suck in other monsters and take their powers, killing them in the process. The group has to stop that monster somehow. The deaths of those monsters were extremely sad as characters were bonded with them emotionally and the development of characters is amazing.

When I watched it it reminded me of Pokemon but with cards instead of Pokeballs, and I'm pretty sure that the main character had a monster similar to Pikachu and could fly by spinning its tail.

Answer (score 1):

The only card based anime with monster fights I can remember is Yu-Gi-Oh

[image]

It was first animated in 1998 and a second time in 2000 until 2004.

There is one character - Motuba Kaiba, the little brother of Seto Kaiba - who is first an antagonist, but becomes a valuable friend after the main character and his friends recued him.

See the related articles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Yu-Gi-Oh!_characters) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!) at Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: I feel like Cardcaptors would also fit under the description of "card-based anime with monster fights".

Comment: It is not Yu-Gi-Oh or CardCaptors, it's been years since I saw it but the little bit I remember was very similar to Pokemon, but with cards instead of Pokeballs (the animation style is similar to Pokemon Black and white).

Comment: Also, I know that I can't have seen it any longer than 9 years ago since at around the same time I also saw an episode of Ben 10 that came out in 2012

Answer (score 0):

The mot similar thing that I can think of is "[Cardfight!! Vanguard](https://cardfight.fandom.com/wiki/Cardfight!!_Vanguard_Wiki)" or one of its future seasons. It aired at around 2011-2012.

Another one that was aired a bit later around 2014 is "[Future Card Buddyfight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Card_Buddyfight)" Or one of its later seasons.

There are also Duel Masters, Bakugan, and Bakegyamon (unlikely in my opinion)

Comment: It's definitely not Bakugan, Duel Masters, or Bakegyamon. I don't think it's any of the Cardfight ones because I don't remember the characters battling with decks of cards, they each had one card that acted like a Pokeball. If it helps the intro was mostly black, grey, and white in colour (maybe with some red?) also the monster that absorbs other monsters was a dragon of some type, I THINK it was white, and it might have had 3 heads... But I don't remember it very well...